# lsof is frozen inside the container

Tags: linux, selinux, lsof

I'm using Fedora 36 and running the container this way:

```bash
docker run --user 0 --rm \
    --privileged \
    --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE \
    --volume=$(pwd)/.env:/legacy/app/.env \
    --volume=$(pwd)/start.sh:/legacy/app/start.sh  \
    --volume=$(pwd)/nginx.conf:/legacy/app/nginx.conf \
    --volume=$(pwd)/php-fpm.conf:/legacy/app/php-fpm.conf \
    --volume=$(pwd)/.nginx:/legacy/app/.nginx \
    --volume=$(pwd)/.php-fpm.d:/legacy/app/.php-fpm.d \
    --volume=$(pwd)/.php.ini.d/php.ini:/etc/php.d/php.ini \
    --entrypoint "/legacy/app/start.sh" \
    --name test -p 8080:8080 \
    test:0.2
```

however inside the container I am unable to perform `lsof`, it is always "frozen" and returns no output.

The following commands are from within the container:

```bash
ps aufx | grep master
root          67  0.0  0.0  10708  2276 pts/0    S+   19:06   0:00  \_ grep --color=auto master
root          24  0.0  0.0 470572 11400 ?        Ss   18:03   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/legacy/app/php-fpm.conf)
root          28  0.0  0.0  39612  7820 ?        S    18:03   0:00 nginx: master process nginx -c /legacy/app/nginx.conf

ls -la /proc/28/fd/1
l-wx------. 1 root root 64 Oct 29 18:03 /proc/28/fd/1 -> pipe:[2444664]

lsof | grep 2444664

whoami
root
```

what can be done?

Comment: Have you tailed the log in a different terminal while running the command? It also isn't uncommon for `lsof` to take a long time to return output depending on what's going on in the system.

Comment: @NasirRiley I did try it outside of the container and it works very fast. So this has to be something with selinux or container `cap-add` restrictions.

Comment: Then have you looked at the logs or the processes inside of the container? No one can help you until you've done that as no one but you has the ability to look at the container. Regardless of where `lsof `is run, as I've stated, it's not uncommon for `lsof` to take a long time depending on what's going on.

Comment: The commands above is inside the container @NasirRiley

Comment: I can see that. Like I've asked from the start, have you looked at the logs or any of resources that are being used?

Comment: Run `strace -f -tt -T -yy -q lsof` and see where the lsof command gets stuck.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue today and in my case the reason was a too high ulimit for open files inside the Docker Container.

You can check this by running

```bash
docker run --rm ubuntu bash -c "ulimit -n"
```

If it is over a billion (like in my case) you run into this issue.

I solved it by configuring default ulimits in my `/etc/docker/daemon.json` (see [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#on-linux) for reference):

```json
{
  "default-ulimits": {
    "nofile": {
      "Hard": 1048576,
      "Name": "nofile",
      "Soft": 1048576
    }
  }
}
```

There is also an [open GitHub issue](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/73) where the topic of the defaults limit is discussed but there seems to be no final conclusion yet.

Comment: That's interesting. Did you figure out why the high limit caused lsof to stuck?

Comment: Unfortunately not :( There is a GitHub issue that describes the exact problem as I experienced it but it was resolved in March so I'm not sure if its the same issue or a new one: https://github.com/lsof-org/lsof/issues/281